# Add set of values to map when initialize the map?

Tags: apex, map, set

```
Set<String> setNames = new Set<String>{'Jon', 'Quinton', 'Reid'};
```

I am trying a bit of code below,

```
Map<String, Set<String>> addMap = new Map<string, set<string>>();
if(String nameVar : ListOfNames)
{
   if(addMap.containsKey(nameVar))
   {
     addMap.get(nameVar).addAll(setNames)
   }
   else
   {
      addMap.put(nameVar,new set<String>{setNames})//getting error[ Invalid initial value type Set<String> for Set<String> ].
      addMap.put(nameVar,(new set<String>).addAll(setNames))//getting error.   [ Incompatible value type Boolean for Map<String,Set<String>>]  
   }
}
```

Any suggestion. Little hiccup here !

Comment: `If(String nameVar : ListOfNames)` should be a for loop as you want to iterate the list in the loop i.e. `for(String nameVar: ListOfNames)` Will be better if you could add the error message as well

Comment: I am having having trouble to add the set of value where i mention as error in commnets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
addMap.put(nameVar, new set<String>(setNames));
```

Let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Oops...I didn't think about () brackets. it works now.

Comment: That is just Great!

Comment: The `new Set<String>()` bit isn't strictly required here. `setNames` is already a `Set<String>`, so there's no need for casting or making a new `Set`. The code could simply be `addMap.put(nameVar, setNames);` That said, this pattern is useful if you want to make changes to the names for a given value of `nameVar` without affecting the names stored in the sets for every other value of `nameVar`. Creating a new `Set` from an existing set ends up creating an independent copy of the original.